# Can't call OnItemLockClickListener callback - Android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-dialogfragment, onitemlongclicklistener

I'm trying to get the items in my ListView to by LongClickable, but I can't seem to get it to work. So far I've gotten no results. Could it just be my emulator? I'm using Geny Motion.

I'm using a Fragment: `public class SearchFragment extends Fragment implements OnItemClickListener, OnItemLongClickListener {}`

I've got both:

```
lstView.setOnItemClickListener(this); //This Listener works great
lstView.setOnItemLongClickListener(this); //This Listener is not working
```

and I've written the method:

```
@Override
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
        long arg3) {
    final String TAG = "listDialog";

    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    Fragment prev = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(TAG);
    if (prev != null)
        ft.remove(prev);

    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ListSelectionDialogFragment listDialog = new ListSelectionDialogFragment();
    listDialog.show(ft, TAG);
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Long click!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    System.out.println("Long click!!");
    return true;
}
```

I also have custom XML for the ListItems and when I set that Layout's `longClickable="true"` then I can't even call the normal click event.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Did you add implements OnItemLongClickListener in your activity?
i.e. 
public class MainActivity extends implements OnItemLongClickListener {
}

Comment: I did, yes. I've updated the question to clarify that.

Comment: How about moving your onItemLongClick inside

lstView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

});

or use ListFragment instead if you have a listview in the Fragment.

Comment: Yeah, I have tried that too. It should be the same thing I believe. I have my OnClickListener setup this way and it's working like a charm. So I must be referencing the right ListView. I'm not sure how to make the transition now to a ListFragment. If I simply change to `extends ListFragment` it crashes. But That shouldn't matter given the fact that my other listener is just fine right?

Comment: Oh, I finally realized my problem. When I converted to using a Fragment, I still had code in ActivityMain and for some reason it was calling that code instead of the Fragment code. Thanks tons for your time! Sorry about that.